# Input Arrays Into Weka

Tags: weka

I am fairly new to machine learning and I am trying to use WEKA (GUI) to implement a neural network on a sports data set. My issue is that I want my inputs to be Arrays (each Array is a contestant with stats such as speed, winrate, etc). I am wondering how I can tell WEKA that each input is an array of values.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it in an .arff file. See [this website](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) for detailed information. As the figure below.

[image: view_arff_file]

Or after opening your data in Weka, you can convert it with the help of some filters. I do not know the current format of your data. However, if you can open it in Weka, you can edit your data with many filters. Meanwhile, artificial neural networks only accept numerical values. Among these filters, there are those who convert nominal data to numerical data. I share an image from these filters below. If you are new to this area, I recommend you to watch videos of WekaMOOC (owned by Weka developers.). I think it will be very useful. Good luck.

[Weka_filters_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btIWU.png)